# Disable Viewport center point, Navigation Guide

Tags: interface

How disable the blue center point in 3D viewport?

It should be a simple option somewhere. I've been look around the settings and internet but still no answer.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a dot drawn with the annotation tool. Annotations can be hidden by disabling *Annotations* in the *Viewport Overlays* options. Alternatively you could hold your mouse button on the annotation tool and switch to the eraser, then draw over the dot to remove it permanently. If this solves your problem I can post it as an answer.

Comment: or select the annotation tool (on the left panel), keep pressing ctrl and draw to erase

Comment: It's not an annotation. But a center point of the viewport. Like what you have in the FPS game.

Comment: That's not a thing in Blender, as far as I'm aware. Have you tried erasing it? Based on your description and the screenshot it seems to be an annotation drawn with the placement set to *View* (it will stay at a fixed location in the viewport).

Comment: If it were a grease pencil object, it should show up in the outliner and be selectable.

Comment: It's not grease pencil, not annotation. I'd tried to earse and got error 'Nothing to erase'. And It's a new installation today.

Comment: Can you share the project file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's just a blank file. I'm quite sure it's not any annotation. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KplV0G9b/

Comment: Do you have a NDOF input device? Perhaps the *Show Navigation Guide* is active (*Edit > Preferences > Input > NDOF*). See [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/help-needed-how-to-switch-off-the-blue-dot-in-the-centre-of-the-3d-view/625064) from blenderartists.org as reference.

Comment: Edit > Preferences > Input > NDOF>Show Nevigation Guide. Unchecked and the dot is gone. Thanks for all for being helpful. I don't hvae any NDOF device thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center dot is called *Navigation Guide*.

Go to `Preferences` and uncheck the `Show Navigation Guide`

Edit > Preferences > Input > NDOF> Show Navigation Guide

[image]

Blender Manual

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/editors/preferences/input.html

---

Thank you Robert Gützkow for the answer in comment.